# How to code for dynamic for-loop levels?

Tags: c#, dynamic, recursion, for-loop, traversal

My problem is like this:

I have several lists need to be permuted, but the list numbers are unknowable. And every element numbers in every list are also unknowable. Sicne I would like to traverse all list element combination, like 1) pick A from list 1, A from list 2, A from list 3; 2) ick A from list 1, A from list 2, B from list 3 ... for ALL permutation.

I use nested for-loop to traverse, like if I have two lists, then:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].EnergyParameters.ListEnergyLevelCandidates.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < list[1].EnergyParameters.ListEnergyLevelCandidates.Count; j++)
            {
                // Do sth
            }
        }
```

If I have three lists, then:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].EnergyParameters.ListEnergyLevelCandidates.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < list[1].EnergyParameters.ListEnergyLevelCandidates.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < list[2].EnergyParameters.ListEnergyLevelCandidates.Count; k++)
                {
                    // Do sth
                }
            }
        }
```

Because the list numbers are unknowable, so the nest numbers are unknowable, which means, I don't know how many levels of for-loop needs to be written.

Under this kind of circumstance, how can I write code for dynamic for-loop levels? I don't want to write 10 loops for 10 lists.

Answer (score 12):

In case you do not know how many lists there are, you do not write nested loops: instead, you write recursion. At each level of the invocation you loop a single list, like this:

```
void AllCombos(List<string>[] lists, int level, string[] current) {
    if (level == lists.Length) {
        // Do somthing; items of current[] contain elements of the combination
    } else {
        foreach (var s in lists[level]) {
            current[level] = s;
             AllCombos(lists, level+1, current);
        }
    }
}
```

Call `AllCombos` as follows:

```
var lists = new List<string>[10];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    lists[i] = PopulateMyList(i);
}
string[] current = new string[lists.Length];
AllCombos(lists, 0, current);
```

Comment: Does this still exexute multi-loop?

Comment: @Asker It does. Although the loops are not textually nested in the source of the program, they are nested at the execution time. See how the `AllCombos` calls itself? This is where the "magic" happens (although there is decidedly nothing magical about it).

Comment: why & what is 10? Is it maximum depth assumed or what?

Comment: And also what is PopulateMyList(i)? Where it is defined?

Comment: You answer helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you need to iterate over an unknown number of for or foreach loops. For example, let's say we have the following collection of collections of strings:

```
var data = new List<List<string>>{
 new List<string>{"red", "green", "blue"},
 new List<string>{"apple", "banana", "peach", "mellon"},
 new List<string>{"one", "two"}
};

private static void Main()
 {
  var data = new List<List<string>>
  {
    new List<string> {"red", "green", "blue"},
    new List<string> {"apple", "banana", "peach", "mellon"},
    new List<string> {"one", "two"}
  };

  foreach (var item in IterateDynamicLoop(data).Select(x => string.Join("-", x)))
    Console.WriteLine(item);

  Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> IterateDynamicLoop<T>(IList<List<T>> data)
{
 var count = data.Count;

 var loopIndex = count - 1;
 var counters = new int[count];
 var bounds = data.Select(x => x.Count).ToArray();

 do
 {
    yield return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(x => data[x][counters[x]]);
 } while (IncrementLoopState(counters, bounds, ref loopIndex));
}

private static bool IncrementLoopState(IList<int> counters, IList<int> bounds, ref int loopIndex)
{
 if (loopIndex < 0)
    return false;

counters[loopIndex] = counters[loopIndex] + 1;

var result = true;

if (counters[loopIndex] >= bounds[loopIndex])
{
    counters[loopIndex] = 0;
    loopIndex--;
    result = IncrementLoopState(counters, bounds, ref loopIndex);
    loopIndex++;
 }

 return result;
}
```